# Display username according to number

Tags: php, mysql

I have database table with users. There is one column called `fkhouseid` which can be (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) it connects user to the house which leads to another table with house names.
I am trying to print each user in separate column for each house. Here is first query to get users:

```
  $numbers = '12345';
  $unityResult =  getUnityEmail();
```

Then get number of houses:

```
  $houseResult = getHouses();   
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($houseResult);
```

There are 5 houses in total. Then I am trying to print names for each house:

```
  for ($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
    echo "<div id='memberList$x' style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:top'>";
    echo "<fieldset class=fieldname style='display:inline'>";
    if( $numbers[$x] == 1){ echo "<legend class=name_legend>u</legend>"; }
    else if( $numbers[$x] == 2){ echo "<legend class=name_legend>n</legend>"; }
    else if( $numbers[$x] == 3){ echo "<legend class=name_legend>i</legend>"; }
    else if( $numbers[$x] == 4){ echo "<legend class=name_legend>t</legend>"; }
    else{ echo "<legend class=name_legend>y</legend>"; }
    echo "<ul class='list'>";
    while ($row_unity = mysqli_fetch_array($unityResult)) { 
      if ($row_unity['fkhouseid'] == $numbers[$x]) {
        format_member_list_filters( $row_unity);
      }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
    mysqli_data_seek($houseResult, 0);
  }
```

I am to get houses(each letter for each house) but I am not able to get names according their houses:

[image]

How I can make it display names for other columns too?

Comment: Can you provide dumps of `$houseResult`, `$unityResult` and check what comes to `$row_unity`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was easy to solve.

```
mysqli_data_seek($houseResult, 0);
```

Changed to

```
mysqli_data_seek($unityResult, 0);
```